# Can Erlang file create .beam file for the imported Erlang file?

Tags: erlang

Can Erlang file create `.beam` file for the imported Erlang file?

For example I have `test1.erl` and `test2.erl` file and `test1.erl` is imported in `test2.erl`. Then compiling `test2.erl` using

```
erlc test2.erl
```

Then, will it create only `test2.beam` or
both `test1.beam` and `test2.beam`?

Comment: Don't use `-import`. See the [Erlang module documentation](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html#pre-defined-module-attributes), which explains that the only thing `-import` does is allow the imported function to "be called the same way as local functions, that is, without any module prefix." That's it, nothing more. Erlang programmers generally avoid `-import` because it makes code more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need compile both files `test1.erl` and `test2.erl`.

```
$ erlc test1.erl test2.erl
```

Comment: is there any other way to get the test1.beam file while running test2.erl file instead of compiling test1.erl independently??

Comment: Yes, you can create application use `Rebar`(https://www.rebar3.org) or `ErlangMK`(https://erlang.mk), those tools will help you compile all files automatically in build project process. In other cases you need or compile all files by hands or create `Makefile` with bash script for to do it, eg: https://github.com/vkatsuba/enn/blob/master/Makefile.